.NET Standard 2.0 equivalent of Int128Converter
I have this C# code:
string x = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000056bc75e2d63100000";
new System.ComponentModel.Int128Converter().ConvertFromString(x).Dump();

It works in my .NET 8 project. I cannot use it in my .NET Standard 2.0 Xamarin Forms project. What is the equivalent?

Have you tried System.Numerics.BigInteger?

That's a really silly way to parse a string to an integer by the way. Int128.Parse(x) is the canonical way to do it.

@Blindy I tried Int128.Parse but it's not recognizing it in VS

@user3776241, with all due respect, then you tried it wrong. Here's the function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int128.parse?view=net-8.0#system-int128-parse(system-string)

@Blindy it's.NET 7+, see the applies to section.

I know it is, I was correcting his parsing code from the question, not providing a pre-Net7 equivalent.

@GuruStron System.ComponentModel.Int128Converter is .NET 7+ as well

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138267/hexadecimal-to-biginteger-conversion

Anyway, Int128 isn't available in .NET Standard either, just .NET 7+. So it makes sense that there's no way to parse a string into an Int128, since Int128 doesn't exist. Use a BigInteger on earlier .NET versions, as @Steven said.

Your string represents a 256 bit long integer.

Your question doesn't make sense, it's not about what function to use, it's about the fact that there is no Int128 type in .Net Standard 2.0. Even if you wrote your own parsing function, there wouldn't be a type to smush it into.
So you either use it as a string (for example, to display), or use BigInteger to use it in arithmetical operations, albeit at a very large performance penalty.

Another option is to drop to native code through P/Invoke or C++/CLI, C++ does support 128-bit types and arithmetic.
